# Starting: Intent shows a blank screen on a real device and I do not get any error with adb logcat

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I do not know why but suddenly my react-native project does not start anymore 
on an android real device.
Two days ago it worked like a charm.
Now I always get a blank screen after these verbose messages:

```
102 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 98 up-to-date
Running adb -s F7AZFG015283 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on F7AZFG015283 (adb -s F7AZFG015283 shell am start -n com.etc/com.etc.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.etc/.MainActivity }
```

It seems the app freezes on the phone.

The version of react-native is 0.56.0.
I tried with:

```
adb logcat
```

but I do not see any errors.
I also tried these commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean
rm -rf android/build
npm install
```

But still I was not able to solve.

**UPDATE**

It seems the problem could be react-native-facebook-sdk and the meta-name element you have to add in AndroidManifest file.

I created a new project with ignite and:

- added react-native-facebook-sdk: it works;
- edited MainApplication.java as package install instructions: it works;
- added this line "`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`" to the AndroidManifest.xml file: IT DOES NOT WORKS, I have blank screen.

The element "facebook_app_id" exists in string.xml, and its value is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue with the latest version of the Facebook SDK for Android (4.36.0) that was released on August 29, 2018.

I was able to fix this by following the advice in this thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17147#issuecomment-351930384

You have to use a specific version of the facebook-android-sdk in your `android/build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```